# Move range of data between workbooks using loop

Tags: excel, vba

I found code similar to the following where the data from one workbook is moved to another by using a loop. The code works except for the information that it moves is incorrect.  Could someone tell me why it keeps copying the last column X number of times (where X = number of rows)? I want to copy the data between A2 and J11 only once instead of X rows of J2 and X rows of J3, and so on.

```
Sub CopySample()
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lCol As Range, lRow As Range
Dim CurCell_1 As Range, CurCell_2 As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'~~> Change as applicable
Set wb1 = Workbooks("Sample1.xlsm")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("OverallData_Month_X.xlsm")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("SampleSheet")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("All Cylinders Data") '<~~ Change as required

For Each lCol In ws1.Range("A2:J11")
'~~> Why this?
Set CurCell_2 = ws2.Range("A2:J2")
For Each lRow In ws1.Range("A2:J11")
    Set CurCell_1 = ws1.Cells(lRow.Row, lCol.Column)
    If Not IsEmpty(CurCell_1) Then
        CurCell_2.Value = CurCell_1.Value
        Set CurCell_2 = CurCell_2.Offset(1)
    End If
Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but try changing this line `Set CurCell_2 = ws2.Range("A2:J2")` to :

```
Set CurCell_2 = ws2.Cells(1, lCol.Column)
```

**UPDATE**

Overall it seems that the above code is setting it's references to different sections of the workbook, and offsetting (moving) those references. I'd argue that there are more efficant ways to do this, and easier ways to code it as well. so while the above answer only solved half of the problems you were having, i've rewritten your code below so that it'll hopefully make more sence to you for you to understand + update.

I believe the below code example does what you're trying to accomplish:

(comments in code)

```
Sub CopySample

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Sample1.xlsm")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("OverallData_Month_X.xlsm")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("SampleSheet")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("All Cylinders Data")

Dim rngCopyFromRange As Range
Set rngCopyFromRange = ws1.Range("A2:J11") '- name the copy range for ease of read

Dim rngPasteStartCell As Range
Set rngPasteStartCell = ws2.Range("A2") 'top left cellt o begin the paste


Dim lCurrentColumn As Long
Dim lCurrentRow As Long

    For lCurrentColumn = 1 To rngCopyFromRange.Columns.Count 'for each column in the source data
        For lCurrentRow = 1 To rngCopyFromRange.Rows.Count '-for each row in each column in source data
            'set the offset of the starting cell's value equal ot the top left cell in the source data offset by the same amount
            '- where the offsets are equal to the row/column we are on - 1
            rngPasteStartCell.Offset(lCurrentRow - 1, lCurrentColumn - 1).Value = _
                rngCopyFromRange.Cells(1, 1).Offset(lCurrentRow - 1, lCurrentColumn - 1).Value
        Next lCurrentRow
    Next lCurrentColumn

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem of the multiple columns. The other problem is that the data from the first row is copied 10x into the preceeding rows and the trend follows for the second through eleventh row copying every source row 10x in the destination file.

Comment: Updated answer to re-do code in a way that you may find easier to read + update.

Comment: Would it be possible to start the paste at a cell that changes depending on the last row used?

Comment: Yes, thats hwy i separated it out so you could modify that line as you'd like.. That would look something like this `rngPasteStartCell = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Range("A" & ws2.rows.count).end(xlup).row + 1)`

Comment: I get a Run_time error 9 when I changed the Range of the source from 11 to 730. I googled the meaning and most referenced the excel not finding the specified file. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I am unsure what the cause of your error 9 is without seeing it in context of your current code. May I suggest that you close this answered question and post a new one with the new updated code.